# how use odoo onchange method on current non saved order lines?

Tags: python, odoo, onchange, odoo-12

I'm working on update the sale order lines with discount value, and there is some product has an option no discount, that means ignoring then while distributing the discount values on the lines

here is the method

```
@api.onchange('discount_type', 'discount_rate', 'order_line', 'discount_durar')
def set_lines_discount(self):
    total = discount = 0.0
    for line in self.order_line:
        if self.discount_type == 'percentage':
            if line.no_discount_field:
                line.discount_durar = 0
            else:
                line.discount_durar = self.discount_rate
        else:
            if line.no_discount_field == True:
                line.discount_durar = 0
            else:
                total += (line.product_uom_qty * line.price_unit)
                if self.discount_rate != 0:
                    discount = (self.discount_rate / total) * 100
                else:
                    discount = self.discount_rate
                for line in self.order_line.search([('no_discount_field', '=', False)]):
                    line.discount_durar = discount
```

it's worked well in all conditions except the last one which I used search on it, it needs the order to be saved to be calculated and to loop over the lines.

how can in loop over the lines with a condition before I save the order?

Answer (score 1):

You can use python one-line list comprehension with condition. In your case you can have something like this.

```
[line for line in self.order_line if condition]
```

Comment: Can you define condition for line?

Comment: line.no_discount_field is False

Comment: The following line of code will give you list of the lines where no_discount_field is False

no_discount_field_false_list = [line for line in self.order_line if  line for line in self.order_line == False]

Then you can check if list is not empty do the assignment line.discount_durar = discount


if no_discount_field_false_list:
   line.discount_durar = discount

Answer (score 0):

i changed the search on sale.order.line object with filter

```
for line in self.order_line.filtered(lambda l: not l.no_discount_field):
```

then its worked well